# ExecuteNonQuery() on adding comments doesn't

Tags: c#, oracle

```
query = @"COMMENT ON TABLE CARD IS 'Card Comments';"
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I got error is as follows:

```
ORA-00933: sql command not properly ended
```

Would someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... are you trying to connect to an Oracle database and feed it Microsoft SQL commands?

Comment: get rid of the semi-colon

Comment: @yaakov: [Oracle COMMENT command docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4009.htm#SQLRF01109)

Comment: I need to correct my query as follows;query = @"COMMENT ON TABLE CARD IS 'Card Comments';COMMENT ON COLUMN CARD.CARD_TEXT IS 'Card Text Comments'"